# Pandas moving window over rows

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to apply a function over a moving window centered around the current row?, for example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'},
...                    'B': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 5},
...                    'C': {0: 2, 1: 4, 2: 6}})
>>> df
   C
0  2
1  4
2  6
```

Desired results generates a column D which is the average of the values of the column C of the previous, current and following rows, that is:

```
row 0 => D = (2 + 4)/2     = 3
row 1 => D = (2 + 4 + 6)/3 = 4
row 2 => D = (4 + 6)/2     = 5 

>>> df_final
   C  D
0  2  3
1  4  4
2  6  5
```

Comment: I do not fully understand how `D` is generated; could you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just want a [rolling mean](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.rolling_mean.html#pandas.rolling_mean), with a centred window of 3.  For example:

```
>>> df["D"] = pd.rolling_mean(df["C"], window=3, center=True, min_periods=2)
>>> df
   A  B  C  D
0  a  1  2  3
1  b  3  4  4
2  c  5  6  5
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer: [`pd.rolling_mean` was deprecated in 0.18](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/whatsnew.html?highlight=rolling_mean#window-functions-are-now-methods) and is no longer available as of pandas=0.23.4.

> Window functions are now methods
>
> Window functions have been refactored to be methods on `Series/DataFrame` objects, rather than top-level functions, which are now deprecated. This allows these window-type functions, to have a similar API to that of `.groupby`.

It either needs to be called on the [dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html):

```
In [55]: df['D'] = df['C'].rolling(window=3, center=True, min_periods=2).mean()

In [56]: df
Out[56]:
   A  B  C    D
0  a  1  2  3.0
1  b  3  4  4.0
2  c  5  6  5.0
```

Or from [pandas.core.window.Rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.window.Rolling.mean.html):

```
In [57]: df['D'] = pd.core.window.Rolling(df['C'], window=3, center=True, min_periods=2).mean()

In [58]: df
Out[58]:
   A  B  C    D
0  a  1  2  3.0
1  b  3  4  4.0
2  c  5  6  5.0
```